# JQuery moving items between SELECT with filtering unexpected behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is a live demo: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P9QQ9/1/)

The filtering is working great for the box on the left.

The moving items between the two lists also works great.

The problem occurs when I move an item into the right box, then filter, it removes everything from the right box.

**How can I have it leave items in the right box upon filtering and not have those items show up in the left box if they are in the right box (to avoid duplicates)?**

```
//MOVE SPECS BETWEEN BOXES
    function moveListItems(sourceID, destinationID) {
        var whatToMove = $("#"+sourceID+"  option:selected");

        if ( sourceID = "excluded-select" ) {
            whatToMove.attr('class', 'included-option');
        }
        if ( sourceID = "included-select" ) {
            whatToMove.attr('class', 'excluded-option');
        }

        whatToMove.remove().appendTo("#"+destinationID);
        return false;
    }

    $("#move-right-btn").click(function(){
        moveListItems("excluded-select", "included-select");
        return false;
    });

    $("#move-left-btn").click(function(){
        moveListItems("included-select", "excluded-select");
        return false;
    });




    var $opts = $(".excluded-option");

    $("#filter-specs-text").keyup(function () {
        var searchString = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        $("#excluded-select").empty().append($opts);

        $(".excluded-option").each(function () {
            var text = $(this).text().toLowerCase();

            //found a match - show this entry
            if (text.indexOf(searchString) > -1) {
                $(this).prop("disabled", false);
            }

            //no match - hide this entry
            else {
               $(this).prop("disabled", true).detach();
            }
        });

    });
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is the `$opts` always contains all the `.excluded-option`s, in the `onkeyup` handler you write, it appends all `$opts` to the first select and filter the list then, that's why the included options (which should be kept in the second select) are pushed back to the first. To solve this you have to update the `$opts` each time you move the items between the 2 selects:

```
$("#filter-specs-text").keyup(function () {
  //...
  //Use $opts here instead of $('.excluded-option')
  $opts.each(function () {
    //...
  }
}
function moveListItems(sourceID, destinationID) {
     var whatToMove = $("#"+sourceID+"  option:selected");         
     //here you update the $opts accordingly...
     if(sourceID == "excluded-select") $opts = $opts.not(whatToMove);
     else $opts = $opts.add(whatToMove);

     whatToMove.remove().appendTo("#"+destinationID);
 return false;
}
```

Note that you should update the `$opts` instead of re-select the `.excluded-option` everytime the `keyup` is triggered, it's so terrible to do it that way.

### [Demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/P9QQ9/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are selecting $opts upfront, those items selected will stay the same even though you change their class or id. You have to reselect them on your keyup event handler.

Comment: Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/P9QQ9/2/  But unfortunately it has the same behavior. thank you for your suggestion though

Comment: Sorry, I was on the wrong path and edited my answer. This should work better, but you have to preserve/store the removed items somehow: http://jsfiddle.net/P9QQ9/3/

Comment: It's closer for sure but as the list is filtered & un-filtered (backspaced) all the original items in the list are not restored.

Comment: Yes, I see clone() was the eventual solution. Thank you for the help. I think this might help others as well.